# Java card PBKDF2 implementation

Tags: javacard

I am trying to implement the pbkdf2 on java card, but the card doesnot support the same. Can someone help.

Comment: Besides my answer, code requests are off topic on Stackoverflow.

Comment: PBKDF2 only requires HMAC, and HMAC only requires a secure hash as underlying primitive; implementation of PBKDF2 should definitely be possible.

Answer (score 5):

PBKDF2 is a key strengthening algorithm. Although top of the line smart card processors are getting near 100 MHz by now (some 33 times the speed of my old MSX, and that's not including advances in caching, instructions and timings), it is not a good idea to perform a function such as PBKDF2 on a smart card.

The idea of PBKDF2 is that you trade off CPU cycles with security of the input keying material. Unfortunately any desktop processor core will be at least 50 times the performance of a smart card processor. So even if we do not consider paralellization, an adversary will have an advantage of at least 50 over the implementation.

Instead you could use [`OwnerPIN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacard/framework/OwnerPIN.html) which has a retry count, which limits the number of tries by the adversary. Another possibility is to use a split implementation of PBKDF2 (or PBKDF2 followed by a key based KDF / HMAC) where only the last step is performed on the smart card.

Comment: If you just want a time-out you could use any slow cryptographic algorithm in a loop, but beware that time-outs depend on CPU speed, and CPU speed depends on the amount of power delivered to the chip. You may need some CPU specific configuration and testing. Of course it is completely possible to implement PBKDF2 in a smart card and yes, you could protect the result in the OwnerPIN as well.

Answer (score 2):

(An addition to an [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49129630/5128464) that should be accepted)

Citing a [thesis](https://is.muni.cz/th/mvf3o/) where author implemented optimized PBKDF2 in javacard (emphasis mine):

> Our implementation takes **136 seconds to compute
> an HMAC_SHA1 with 2048 iterations**. Using a different hashing algorithm, such as SHA-256, did not raise the computation time significantly, only to 148 seconds. This means that just to conform to Kerberos
> standard, we would need 4 minutes to compute the key. **Generating
> the key for VeraCrypt partition encryption would take more than 4
> hours**.

The respective implementation is [here](https://github.com/MiragePV/OptimizedJCAlgs/blob/master/Pbkdf2/src/PBKDF2.java) (I have never used it or verified it).