# Problem using PBKDF2 algorithm on javacard to convert mnemonic phrase to seed

Tags: smartcard, pbkdf2

I am trying to Convert cryptocurrency mnemonic phrase to seed using a smart card. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49125201/java-card-pbkdf2-implementation/74127459#74127459) question and the perfect answer. I am trying to use the same code for my conversion with a little modification I have made. This is the applet code:

```java
    import javacard.framework.*;
    
    /**
     *
     * @author Matej Evin
     * 6th March 2018
     */
     
    public class PBKDF2Applet extends javacard.framework.Applet
    {
        final static byte CLA_SIMPLEAPPLET              = (byte) 0xB0;
        final static byte INS_MESSAGE_DIGEST            = (byte) 0x61;
        final static short ARRAY_LENGTH                 = (short) 0xff;
        final static short SW_OBJECT_NOT_AVAILABLE      = (short) 0x6711;
    
        private   PBKDF2  m_pbkdf2 = null;
        private byte m_ramArray1[] = null;
        private byte m_ramArray2[] = null;
        private byte m_ramArray3[] = null;
        private byte password[] = null;
        private final byte salt[] = {(byte)'m',(byte)'n',(byte)'e',(byte)'m',(byte)'o',(byte)'n',(byte)'i',(byte)'c'};
        private byte m_dataArray[] = null;
    
        protected PBKDF2Applet(byte[] buffer, short offset, byte length)
        {
            short dataOffset = offset;
            boolean isOP2 = false;
    
            if(length > 9) {
                
                dataOffset += (short)( 1 + buffer[offset]);
                dataOffset += (short)( 1 + buffer[dataOffset]);
                dataOffset++;
    
                m_dataArray = new byte[ARRAY_LENGTH];
                Util.arrayFillNonAtomic(m_dataArray, (short) 0, ARRAY_LENGTH, (byte) 0);
                
                m_ramArray1 = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short) 0xff, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);
                m_ramArray2 = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short) 0xff, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);
                m_ramArray3 = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short) 0xff, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);
                password    = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short) 0xff, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);
                
                m_pbkdf2 = PBKDF2.getInstance(PBKDF2.ALG_SHA_512);
    
                isOP2 = true;
    
            } else {}
                register();
        }
        
        public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) throws ISOException
        {
            new PBKDF2Applet(bArray, bOffset, bLength);
        }
    
        public boolean select()
        {
            return true;
        }
    
        public void deselect()
        {
            return;
        }
    
        public void process(APDU apdu) throws ISOException
        {
            byte[] apduBuffer = apdu.getBuffer();
            
            if (selectingApplet())
                return;
    
            if (apduBuffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] == CLA_SIMPLEAPPLET) {
                switch ( apduBuffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS] )
                {               
                    case INS_MESSAGE_DIGEST:
                        Pbkdf2(apdu);
                    break;
                    
                    default :
                        ISOException.throwIt( ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED ) ;
                    break ;
    
                }
            }
            else ISOException.throwIt( ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }
        
        
        public void Pbkdf2(APDU apdu){
            byte[]    buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
            short     passLen = apdu.setIncomingAndReceive();
            Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(buffer, (short)ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA , password, (short)0, passLen);
                                         
            short retLen = m_pbkdf2.doFinal(password, (short) 0, passLen,
                                         salt, (short) 0, (short) 8,
                                         (short) 2048,
                                         m_ramArray3, (short) 0);
            
            Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(m_ramArray3, (short) 0, buffer, (short)0, retLen);
            apdu.setOutgoingAndSend(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, retLen);
        }
    }
```

and this is the pbkdf2 class where I have added sha512 supported in Javacard 3.0.5 and above:

```java
    import javacard.framework.JCSystem;
    import javacard.framework.Util;
    import javacard.security.MessageDigest;
    import javacard.security.CryptoException;
    import javacard.security.HMACKey;
    import javacard.security.KeyBuilder;
    import javacard.security.Signature;
    
    
    /**
     *
     * @author Matej Evin
     * 03 August 2018
     */
    
    public class PBKDF2 {
        
        public static final byte  ALG_SHA            = 1;
        public static final byte  ALG_SHA_256        = 4;
        public static final byte  ALG_SHA_512        = 6;
        public static final byte  LENGTH_SHA         = 20;
        public static final byte  LENGTH_SHA_256     = 32;
        public static final byte  LENGTH_SHA_512     = 64;
        public static final short BLOCKSIZE_SHA      = 128;
        private final static short SALT_LEN          = 16;
        private final static short  SZERO           = (short) 0x0;
        private final static byte   BZERO           = (byte)  0x0;
        private final static byte   BONE            = (byte)  0x01;
        private static short mdlen;
        
        private byte[] U_i                          = null;
        private byte[] keyprime                     = null;
        private byte[] innerblock                   = null;
        private byte[] outerblock                   = null;
        
        private         MessageDigest   m_hash      = null;
        private static  PBKDF2          m_instance  = null;
        
        protected PBKDF2() {}
        
        public static PBKDF2 getInstance(byte algorithm) throws CryptoException {
            if (m_instance == null)
            {
                m_instance = new PBKDF2();
                
                switch(algorithm) {
                    case ALG_SHA:
                        m_instance.m_hash = MessageDigest.getInstance(ALG_SHA, false);
                        PBKDF2.mdlen  = LENGTH_SHA;
                        break;
                    case ALG_SHA_256:
                        m_instance.m_hash = MessageDigest.getInstance(ALG_SHA_256, false);
                        PBKDF2.mdlen  = LENGTH_SHA_256;
                        break;
                    case ALG_SHA_512:
                        m_instance.m_hash = MessageDigest.getInstance(ALG_SHA_512, false);
                        PBKDF2.mdlen  = LENGTH_SHA_512;
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new CryptoException(CryptoException.NO_SUCH_ALGORITHM);
                }
                
                m_instance.U_i        = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray(mdlen, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);                         
                m_instance.keyprime   = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray(BLOCKSIZE_SHA, JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);                 
                m_instance.innerblock = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short)(BLOCKSIZE_SHA + mdlen), JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);
                m_instance.outerblock = JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray((short)(BLOCKSIZE_SHA + mdlen), JCSystem.CLEAR_ON_DESELECT);
            }
            return m_instance;
        }
        
        private short hmac(byte[] K, short KOffset, short KLength, short mLength) {
            
            if (KLength < BLOCKSIZE_SHA) {
                Util.arrayFillNonAtomic(keyprime, KLength, (short)(BLOCKSIZE_SHA-KLength), BZERO);
                Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(K, KOffset, keyprime, SZERO, KLength);
            } else
            if (KLength > BLOCKSIZE_SHA)
            {
                m_hash.doFinal(K, KOffset, KLength, keyprime, SZERO);
            } else {
                Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(K, KOffset, keyprime, SZERO, KLength);
            }
            
            for (short i = 0; i < BLOCKSIZE_SHA; i++) {
                innerblock[i] = (byte) (keyprime[i] ^ ((byte) 0x36));
                outerblock[i] = (byte) (keyprime[i] ^ ((byte) 0x5c));
            }
            
            Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(U_i, SZERO, innerblock, BLOCKSIZE_SHA, mLength);
            m_hash.doFinal(innerblock, SZERO, (short) (BLOCKSIZE_SHA+mLength), innerblock, SZERO);
            
            Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(innerblock, SZERO, outerblock, BLOCKSIZE_SHA, mdlen);
            return m_hash.doFinal(outerblock, SZERO, (short) (BLOCKSIZE_SHA+mdlen), U_i, SZERO);
        }
        
        public short doFinal(byte[] password, short passwordOffset, short passwordLength,
                             byte[] salt, short saltOffset, short saltLength,
                             short iterations,
                             byte[] out, short outOffset) throws CryptoException {
            
            if (SALT_LEN < saltLength)
                throw new CryptoException(CryptoException.ILLEGAL_USE);
            
            Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(salt, saltOffset, U_i, SZERO, saltLength);
            U_i[         saltLength     ] = BZERO;
            U_i[(short) (saltLength + 1)] = BZERO;
            U_i[(short) (saltLength + 2)] = BZERO;
            U_i[(short) (saltLength + 3)] = BONE;
            
            hmac(password, passwordOffset, passwordLength, (short) (saltLength + 4));
            Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(U_i, SZERO, out, outOffset, mdlen);
            for (short k = 1; k < iterations; k++) {
                hmac(password, passwordOffset, passwordLength, mdlen);
                for (short j = 0; j < mdlen; j++) {
                    out[(short) (outOffset + j)] ^= U_i[j];
                }
            }
            
            return mdlen;
        }
    }
```

As I wanted to implement mnemonic to seed algorithm as described in [this](https://learnmeabitcoin.com/technical/mnemonic#mnemonic-to-seed) link, I have used a mnemonic phrase randomly generated [here](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/) as:

`broken crazy ankle modify false review ship sell beyond suspect orchard acoustic plate client design soup olympic curve treat retreat crunch funny next mammal`

which should result in the 64-byte seed below calculated by the same site:

`392b80adbd0ebb1d629410a187cdf74ae8ee18a70d11171e553adf5fd876b4173cd618d81f442120eefdf0cd5a92cdb0a6f79b6d404e326f68ab5e99b8a38d5e`

but, unfortunately, my code above results in this seed:

`0EBB1D629410A187CDF74AE8EE18A70D11171E553ADF5FD876B4173CD618D81F442120EEFDF0CD5A92CDB0A6F79B6D404E326F68AB5E99B8A38D5E7065637420`

I don't know where did I make a mistake modifying the code!

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code ends with `apdu.setOutgoingAndSend(ISO7816.OFFSET_CDATA, retLen);` but the line before you do `Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(m_ramArray3, (short) 0, buffer, (short)0, retLen);` where you copy to offset 0 in your buffer. As a result you are sending from buffer at an offset of 5 but the response you want starts at 0. Changing the code to `apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short) 0, retLen);` would solve the problem.

Comment: Such a ridiculous mistake!

Comment: @MJay If any Javacard developer ever tries to claim they never made exactly this type of mistake they'd be lying. Such an easy mistake to make and we've all pretty much made it.